# SparkBWA cannot find file spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I follow the link https://github.com/citiususc/SparkBWA for installing SparkBWA:

```
git clone https://github.com/citiususc/SparkBWA.git
cd SparkBWA
mvn package
```

In the 'Running SparkBWA' section it said to run it with the command:

`spark_dir/bin/spark-submit --class com.github.sparkbwa.SparkBWA SparkBWA-0.2.jar -h`

but I dont have *spark-submit* command installed.

How can I have *spark-submit*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install Spark dependencies (JRE or JDK 1.7 or 1.8, newer Java versions are not supported).
- Download supported version from Spark Downloads page (looks like it is pretty 
  old, so you might have to use 1.x branch). For simple tests use prebuilt variant with bundled Hadoop libs.
- Unpack the content and use `bin/spark-submit` command from the newly created directory.